# Changing the same variable for all existing subthreads

Tags: java, multithreading, resize, synchronized

sorry in advance if that question did get asked before somewhere here. I really tried to find something that helps me. Sadly I had no luck.

Here is my situation:

I have a Frame class with a button and a slider. And I have a thread class. With the button in the frame class, I create instances of the thread class. One instance of a thread class represents an picture. All the subthreads(pictures) will be displayed in the same frame and move around with a certain interval.

Here is my problem:

The slider controles the interval of the moving pictures. So they move faster or slower. All pictures should get faster or slower simultaneously. Unluckily only the first created thread gets affected by the slider. Same problem is with my ComponentAdapter that has his componentResized function. All the threads(or the pictures) should get bigger or smaller simultaneously relatively to the frame size.

Here I will try to show you roughly how I am doing it:

frame class:

```
//The actionPerformed for the button that keeps creating threads
//Every thread is a picture (ant in this case) that
// moves through the same field of buttons
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    a = new AmeiseThread(this);
    a.start();
}


// The slider in the frame.When it changes, also the picture movement speed    changes

sliderKind.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();
            if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                int speed = source.getValue();
                a.sleeptime = 1000 / speed;
            }

        }
    });


// Whenever the Frame gets resized, it will change the Pictures
// on its buttons relatively to its new size

class MyComponentAdapter extends ComponentAdapter {
     public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {

            xScale = jbArray.get(1).getSize().width;
            yScale = jbArray.get(1).getSize().height;

            a.ameisen.clear();

            a.ameisen.add(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("ameise.gif").getImage()
                    .getScaledInstance(xScale, yScale, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
            a.ameisen.add(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("ameise90.gif").getImage()
                    .getScaledInstance(xScale, yScale, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
            a.ameisen.add(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("ameise180.gif").getImage()
                    .getScaledInstance(xScale, yScale, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
            a.ameisen.add(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("ameise270.gif").getImage()
                    .getScaledInstance(xScale, yScale, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
    }
}
```

I can't think of anything that is written in my thread class, that could be of interest. I think the problem lies within my already posted code somewhere. But if you do need more informations, comment it and I will post more informations right away.

Sorry again, if that question already exists. I feel like it does, because it sounds rather simple. Though I really tried to find a question similar to this but I had no luck.

Comment: you should use static field or save all the threads you create and itarate on it when the slider changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save all the threads you create

```
 threadList.add(a);
```

itarate over it when the slider changed

```
 for (AmeiseThread a: threadList)
    if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            int speed = source.getValue();
            a.sleeptime = 1000 / speed;
    }
```